# Convert NTFS to case-insensitive

Tags: ntfs

Can I convert an NTFS volume to case-insensitive? If I can do it by formatting / erasing, that is fine. I have a backup. BTW, I cannot use FAT, exFAT, EXT3, EXT4 or others. I have to use NTFS.

Comment: It's not the volume that's case-insensitive, it's the OS...

Comment: Sorry to say it, but you are wrong. The OS is not case-sensitive. The volume is case sensitive. Anyone else have the real answer?

Comment: Windows is case insensitive when it comes to file/directory names...

Comment: What is an example of something that you want to do, but can't?

Comment: @Lance: The volume contains *data* and *metadata*. Case-sensitivity is a kind of *behavior*. There isn't anything "case-sensitive" about bytes/characters on the disk... it's the *program* that behaves in a case-sensitive way, nothing else.

Comment: @Lance: Also see [this page](http://support.microsoft.com/kb/929110) -- the OS can indeed be case-sensitive if you want it to.

Comment: @Mehrdad, the FS is case sensitive, as it allows those unicode charachters

Comment: @soandos: Then I think you mean "case-preserving", not "case-sensitive"? Because the latter makes no sense... it's like saying "your web page is fast". It's not the page, it's the browser that renders it fast (or the server that processes it fast).

Comment: Lance, @soandos: Furthermore, notice that the [`OBJECT_ATTRIBUTES`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/hardware/ff557749.aspx) structure lets you tell the system whether you want case-sensitive or case-insensitive behavior (`OBJ_CASE_INSENSITIVE`). That would not make any sense if it was a volume-related thing instead of an OS-related thing.

Comment: It is more about the format of the drive, rather than the OS, though NTFS itself says the formmater can choose. I agree that it is most certainly not one or the other (as stated in my answer).

Answer (score 5):

NTFS is case sensitive (see [here](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/NTFS)) depending on the namespace that it is running under. In a Win32 environment, it will be case insensitive, in other POSIX environments, it will be case sensitive. In essence, it is much more about the OS than the FS (filesystem).

Generally speaking though, this just means that the OS has the *option* of treating something as case insensitive (it could do case insensitive  compare on its own).

There is no change that you are going to change the filesystem in this way to make it case insensitive. It would:

1. require WAY to much low level coding
2. impact all the operating systems that would need to run on the FS

If you are looking for something more specific (say, convert all file names to lower case on the drive) there might be something that can be done, but the filesystem itself will remain unchanged.

Comment: Umm. Wiki says `Allowed characters in filenames: In Posix namespace, any UTF-16 code unit (case sensitive) and In Win32 namespace, any UTF-16 code unit (case insensitive)`..

Comment: In Adobe Photoshop CS5 installer, I am allowed to choose the destination to install. If I choose the NTFS volume, the installer says "cannot install on a case-sensitive volume".

Comment: @Bibhas: Did you see that it said `In Win32 namespace`? That has **nothing** to do with the volume; it's simply a part of the OS.

Comment: @Lance, It is most definetly possible to run CS5 on NTFS without changing it.. according to something I found on google, you can fix your issue by "Navigate to Adobe Photoshop CS.app » (Control-Click and choose Show Package Contents » Contents » Resources » asn. In that folder, there should be a single file called PS.SIF. Rename the file to PS.sif, and Photoshop should now launch. The same thing needs to be done to ImageReady to get it to work."

Comment: @soandos:Thanks. In your plan, it seems no way to get around the actual installer check. In waiting so long for all this discussion, I got tired of waiting, and just installed on the case-insensitive volume (HFS+). Now I will try copying the app folder to the NTFS volume, use your tiny hack, and see if it works. I have copied older versions of Photoshop to a different volume before and it always works like a champ. This is quite a different bird though.

Comment: @soandos: No asn directory in the Contents.